# How to fetch assets inside vendor subfolders in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, vendor

I need to install a series of libs in my application, keeping them in their respective folders inside `/vendor/plugins/`

Example, the ckeditor library:

- Main folder in `/vendor/plugins/ckeditor/`
- js file in `/vendor/plugins/ckeditor/js/Chart.js`
- css file in `/vendor/plugins/ckeditor/css/chart.min.css`

So that I can import into my application.scss like this:

```
*= require chart.min
```

And in my application.js like this:

```
//= require Chart.js
```

When I try to do this rails only accesses the folder `/vendor/assets/plugins/` plugins, generating the error:

```
could not find file 'chart.min' with type 'text/css'
```

How do I get the project to scan all of the vendor's subfolders until find the file I'm importing?

Comment: I added this to my initializers/assets.rb without success: Rails.application.config.assets.paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/vendor/plugins/*"].sort_by { |dir| -dir.size }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First add the `/vendor/plugins` directory to the assets load path:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor", "plugins")
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
  end
end
```

However adding a directory to the assets load path does not mean that Sprockets will search all the subdirectories recursively. Nor is it a very good idea to configure it to do so.

You still need to provide a complete path from `/vendor/plugins`.

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require ckeditor/js/Chart
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
*= require ckeditor/css/chart.min
```

Or you can just use the [Rails integration gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) and skip all the hassle.

Comment: IMHO I would get rid of the `plugins` directory. Less configuration is usually a good thing.

Comment: I placed plugins folder inside vendor/assets/ and then i could skip the "config.assets.paths" code. I was struggling with the files path, which you nailed with the requires. Thanks!

Comment: Using gem for ckeditor would be easier, the problem is that i need to install 15 libs of specific versions to integrate a html admin dashboard, so it will be easier if i use the files that comes with the package. That's why i need the plugin's folder.